# How do I run a command from a network path in PowerShell/batch file

Tags: sql-server, powershell, cmd, sql-server-2012, winscp

Essentially what I'm trying to run is this:

```
cd /d W:\RemoteMirror\ && winscp.com /ini=nul /script=Remote_Mirror_WinSCP.txt
```

or this:

```
cd /d \\fileServer\RemoteMirror\ && winscp.com /ini=nul /script=Remote_Mirror_WinSCP.txt
```

Of course, with SQL Server, I can't use UNC paths. But I'm not sure how to do it otherwise. I'm not too familiar with PowerShell yet, but that'd be my best guess.

Comment: can you run a batch file?

Comment: Your command line starts with `cd`. Are you just trying the change the default folder or are you trying to do something else?

Comment: Use `PUSHD` and `POPD`. If you specify a UNC name, it will allocate an unused drive letter. Read all about it using `PUSHD /?`.

Comment: What do you mean by *"with SQL Server, I can't use UNC paths"*?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu I think the issue is with the SQL Server Service Account not being able to run with full privileges.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Trying to change directories to our local file server and mirror an SFTP file server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNC path cannot be a current working directory (that's a Windows limitation, it has nothing to do with SQL server).

---

As @lit already commented, you can temporarily allocate a drive letter for a UNC path and change working directory to it at once, using [`pushd` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd).

---

Alternatively, modify your WinSCP script not to rely on the current working directory.

Just use full UNC paths in the script, like:

```
get "/remote/path/*" "\\fileServer\RemoteMirror\"
```

See also [Using batch file and WinSCP to download files from the FTP server to file server (shared folder)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43642035/850848)

---

Or, if you need to make the script working with different directories, use a [parameterized script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#arguments):

```
get "/remote/path/*" "%1%\"
```

And run it like:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /script=Remote_Mirror_WinSCP.txt /parameter \\fileServer\RemoteMirror
```

See a full example for using [parameterized scripts](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_multiple_servers).

Comment: I am able to run the script now but the files don't move and the step seems to run infinitely as if the prompt window is awaiting user input. Is there a way to show the cmd window while running it as a scheduled task? @martin-prikryl

Comment: Enable logging using `/log=“C:\path\log.log”` command-line switch.

Comment: So redirect output of `winscp.com` to a file: `winscp.com ... > c:\path\winscp.log`. Do you even have `winscp.com` in `PATH`? Does the script even work, if you execute it manually?

Comment: It does work when executing it manually and it logged when ran manually. It is in the PATH variables. This is what I have in my file that's being called: `# Connect
open sftp://xxx:xxx@xxx.com/ -hostkey="ssh-rsa 2048 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
# Force binary mode transfer
option transfer binary
# Download file to the local directory
synchronize -filemask="*.pgp|*/" local %1% /
# Disconnect
close
# Exit WinSCP
exit`

Comment: `cmd.exe /k "winscp.com /ini=nul /log="C:\tools\log.log" /script=C:\tools\Mirror_WinSCP.txt /parameter \\fs1\dataprocessing\RemoteMirror`     That's what I have in the SQL task. And I just realized that you're the developer for WinSCP. Thank you SO much for helping me with this!

Comment: Did you try the redirecting?

Comment: Like this? `cmd.exe /k "winscp.com /ini=nul /log="C:\tools\log.log" /script=C:\tools\Mirror_WinSCP.txt /parameter \\fs1\dataprocessing\RemoteMirror\ > C:\tools\log.log`?

Comment: Yes. Though why the `cmd /k`?

Comment: I actually don't remember why I had that in there... I guess that would cause the infinite pause in the scheduled task, too, actually... Updated to this: `cd C:\tools\ && winscp.com /ini=nul /script=C:\tools\Mirror_WinSCP.txt /parameter \\fs1\dataprocessing\RemoteMirror\ > C:\tools\log.log` New error is "winscp.com is not recognized as an internal or external command" so it seems like it's not picking up the PATH var even though I installed it for all users...

Comment: With the help of google and your answer in the forums, I found the answer and everything works! https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=24359